# Setting zoom level after selecting Geocoder result

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible in Mapbox GL to set a zoom level after the user selects one search result? My goal is to show at least a few markers on the map around the user. Or is there another way to achieve the same result, like zoom to geocoder marker + nearest marker?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the zoom level that the Mapbox geocoder goes to when there's a result like this:

```
new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
  zoom: 12
})
```

Comment: Actually this is what I have, but it won't change anything. The zoom is the same if I set it to 1 or 20.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, or maybe there's a bug which you should file.

Answer (score 0):

After the user selects a geocoder result, its possible to give him some options to fit specific zoom level, by using the `flyTo` options

```js
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
  flyTo: {
    padding: 15, // If you want some minimum space around your result
    easing: function(t) {
      return t;
    },
    maxZoom: 6, // If you want your result not to go further than a specific zoom
  }
})
```

More options for the `flyTo` property here : https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#flyto

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `zoom` variable from [flyTo](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#flyto)

```
    map.addControl(
      new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        flyTo: {
          bearing: 0,
          speed: 0.8, 
          curve: 1, 
          zoom: 6,
          easing: function (t) {
          return t;
          }
          },
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
      })
    );
```